# History of Cauchy-Euler Equations

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ho.history-overview

As I teach a class in ODE, and following [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/235698/42864) and [Rota's paper](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Rota.pdf), I wandered what is the history of the research of -

> > $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k x^k y^{(k)}(x) = g(x),\quad \forall k=0,\cdots ,n, \, a_k\in \mathbb{R}, \, a_n\neq 0\,. $

There are interesting motivations for it in [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12628/applications-of-euler-cauchy-odes), but I'm mainly interested in the historical aspects.

Comment: Thumbs up for Rota's paper :)

Comment: This seems like a question for [hsm.se]